# Regex - Replacing a matching subgroup

Tags: python, regex

The following code finds in a string the names of regex like groups to be replaced. I would like to use this so as to change the names `name_1`, `name_2` and `not_escaped` to `test_name_1`, `test_name_2` and `test_not_escaped` respectively. In the matches `m`, each name is equal to `m.group(2)`. How can I do that ?

```
p = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\\g<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*)>")

text = r"</\g<name_1>\g<name_2>\\\\\g<not_escaped>\\g<escaped>>>"

for m in p.finditer(text):
    print(
        '---',
        m.group(),
        m.group(2)
    )
```

This gives the following output.

```
---
\g<name_1>
name_1

---
\g<name_2>
name_2

---
\\\\\g<not_escaped>
not_escaped
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to reproduce the whole group 0 text, using `\<digit>` back-references to re-used captured groups:

```
p.sub(r'\1\\g<test_\2>', text)
```

Here `\1` refers to the initial backslashes group, and `\2` to the name to be prefixed by `test_`.

For this to work, you do need to move the `*` *into* the first capturing group to make sure that captured group was not un-matched:

```
p = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\\g<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*)>")
```

I've used a *non-capturing* group (`(?:...)`) to still keep the backslashes grouped together.

Demo:

```
>>> text = r"</\g<name_1>\g<name_2>\\\\\g<not_escaped>\\g<escaped>>>"
>>> p = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\\g<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*)>")
>>> print(p.sub(r'\1\\g<test_\2>', text))
</\g<test_name_1>\g<test_name_2>\\\\\g<test_not_escaped>\\g<escaped>>>
```

Comment: I have to go but I will accept your answer later. This works fine. Thanks !

Comment: I have to use `\\g` instead of `g`. I will correct your answer if you don't have the time to do it. It's time to go for me...

Comment: @projetmbc and Martjin, you can also use `(?:\\.)` instead of `(?:\\\\)`. It's just that I find the former less hard on the eyes :)

Comment: @Jerry: That would match `\!` too, or `\±` or any other character. `.` doesn't repeat, it is itself a meta character that matches *anything* except newline (and even newlines if you set the right flag).

Comment: @MartijnPieters But would that cause a problem? It will get replaced anyway in the `\1` backref, right?

Comment: @Jerry: You'd match the wrong type of text, yes. I qualify that as a problem. What if `\#\g` should not match because that has a different meaning altogether?

Comment: Well, maybe from that perspective... Mine is that those `(?:\\\\)` in the first place are to ensure that the last one before `g` isn't an escaped backslash, to which `(?:\\.)` fulfills just as well. I guess it could be a matter of personal preference. If `\#\g` means something else, then I'd process that first.

Comment: The use of `(?:\\.)` will match bigger texts than (?:\\\\). This doesn't matter here but for my part I prefer the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is by using a series of three simple calls to `str.replace` rather than using regexes for replacement:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"(?<!\\)(\\\\)*\\g<([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z\d_]*)>")

text = r"</\g<name_1>\g<name_2>\\\\\g<not_escaped>\\g<escaped>>>"

for m in p.finditer(text):
    if m.groups(2):
        replacement = m.groups(2)[1]
        text = text.replace(replacement, 'test_' + replacement)
```

Comment: My question doesn't indicate another constraint that makes fail your code which doesn't work with `r"</\g<name_1>\\g<name_1>"` that will become `</\g<test_name_1>\\g<test_name_1>` instead of `</\g<test_name_1>\\g<name_1>`.